# Apache Beam only timely ParDo function with no state

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to write an element to Firestore 1 second after my fixed window closes. I have tried to follow the timely and stateful DoFn guides but they do not have an example of a strictly timely only DoFn anywhere.

```py
# class to write to firestore using DoFn
class WriteToFirestore(beam.DoFn):
    TIMER = userstate.TimerSpec('timer', userstate.TimeDomain.WATERMARK)

    def setup(self):
        from google.cloud import firestore
        self.firestore_client = firestore.Client(project='project ID')

    def process(self, element,
            w=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
            timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(TIMER)):
        timer.set(w.end + Duration(0.5)) # expire 0.5 seconds after window closes

    @userstate.on_timer(TIMER)
    def expiry(self):
        logging.info("FIRED")
```

This code throws `Number of components does not match number of coders`. I do not care about state, I do not need coders (to my understanding). Surely there must be an easy way of doing this?